# How to unhide a program from tray, inserting a key combination?

Tags: java, keylistener, tray

I have a program in tray, and I want it to appear when I enter a key combination, not <kbd>Alt + Key</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl + Key</kbd>, but something like a password, an entire string.

What I have to use? KeyListener or maybe InputEvent?

Comment: So let me get this straight. Your program is not visible, does not have focus, but rather is iconified, and you want it to listen for key presses, much like a key-logger? I would use something other than Java for this such as AutoIt.

Comment: You can't make keyEvents to fire until the focus is on the Application itself.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOFEels Yes, exactly! So, only AutoIt or I can manage it with some java method?

Comment: @eugenio: I think that you would need to use either AutoIt, AutoKeyPress or other similar program (if Windows), or use JNA or JNI. All solutions would have to be platform specific.